# How do private network upgrades work?

Tags: stellar-core

I don't understand how network upgrade work.
When I call the endpoint `/upgrades?mode=set&upgradetime=2019-04-13T20:23:55Z&basefee=1000000&basereserve=1&protocolversion=10`

1. Will the network upgrade immediately?
2. Will the base fee increase to 1M stroop?
3. Will the base reserve change to 1 XLM?
4. What does `protocolversion` mean?
5. Does the command need to be run on all nodes before it will take effect?

Answer (score 3):

1. If the time is set in the past the upgrade will happen immediately after the upgrades are agreed upon by the network. If it is set in the future the upgrade will happen at that time provided enough nodes agree it
2. The base fee will be *set to* 1M stroop (not increased by)
3. The base reserve will be set to 1 *stroop* (it is set in stroop and not XLM)
4. Protocol version is the current protocol version... If you are running a private network I would have thought you would want to be running the latest version which is 10
5. The upgrades are "armed" once you run the command. You can see this when you you check /info in the status field. You need to run the command on each node. Once enough nodes are armed for the network to reach consensus on the upgrade the nodes all execute the upgrades

Take a look [here](https://www.stellar.org/developers/stellar-core/software/commands.html) for more information.